# Run jQuery function on AJAX load except for initial page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a filterable list that uses AJAX to update results. I am trying to add a simple JQuery function to scroll to the first item when a filter is applied. It works fine, except the scroll function runs on initial page load as well as after AJAX filtering. How can I run this only when the filters are updated?

```js
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, request, settings ) {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (jQuery('#td-top-of-list').offset().top - 200)
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is the page: https://galvestondiet.com/galveston-diet-recommended-physicians/

Comment: Don't attach the ajaxComplete until you're ready for it to begin being called.

Comment: Please provide more information on how do you load your list.

Comment: The list is loaded using Elementor page builder in Worpdress and a filtering plugin.

Comment: do you have control on the content of the list? Exemple add a <script> tag that trigger a function on the main page, so you can have a 'loaded' event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @benoit. The plugin author provided me with the completed AJAX event. Here is the working snippet...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $( document ).on( 'jet-filter-content-rendered', function() {  // Completed event
            if($(window).width() > 767) { // Only scroll on tablet & desktop
                $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#top-of-physician-list").offset().top - 200
                }, 1000);  
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is on every ajax completed request on your page.
You need to grab the completed event from the call when you load the list.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://app.asana.com/-/api/0.1/workspaces/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // added data type
    success: function(res) {
        fillYourList(res);
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (jQuery('#td-top-of-list').offset().top - 200)
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But now the scroll goes to the footer. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ZachToth Can you give me the absolute url (and line number) of where you do the scrool ?